# Visual Studio 2019 "Busy" after building solution

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, unreal-engine4

I'm following a tutorial with Unreal Engine 4 that uses Visual Studio 2019.

However whenever i press F7 (Build) it will build fine, but then when i click on the program it displays: [image: Visual Studio is Busy]

I've searched the internet for any fixes but there seem to be little to no help whatsoever and was wondering if anyone on Stack Overflow has come across this issue?

My PC specs are:

- Ryzen 5 3600X
- RX 5700 XT
- 16 GB 3200MHz RAM

I don't have any extensions installed, it's pretty much a fresh install of VS 2019.

Help for fixing this will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bug has been driving me crazy for months. Here are the 2 solutions I know of:

1. Disable the "Visual Studio IntelliCode (AI-assisted developer productivity) in the "Manage Extensions".
2. If you want to keep the IntelliCode extension on, building with Ctrl+b doesn't crash VS. Only building with F7 does.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what David M has said I've also found using the UnrealVS build extension and building using the command UnrealVS.BuildStartupProject has solved this problem for me.

You can find the setup for the plugin and how to keybind the command on the UE4 docs:
https://docs.unrealengine.com/4.27/en-US/ProductionPipelines/DevelopmentSetup/VisualStudioSetup/UnrealVS/